# Accord avec un objet direct

Tags: accord

Cette phrase est-elle correcte quand le pronom se réfère à « *la* juge » ?

> ... des mêmes vices qui l'ont amené à rejeter d'autres aspects du témoignage ...

Faut-il ajouter *-e* à *amené*, comme ceci :

> ... des mêmes vices qui l'ont amenée à rejeter d'autres aspects du témoignage ...

Je pose la question parce que j'ai lu la première dans la décision d'une cour.

Comment: Est-ce que la phrase complète emploie l'article féminin devant le nom i.e. « la juge » ?  Que je sache c'est un nom masculin mais avec l'écriture inclusive on ne sait jamais.

Comment: Oui ; à la départ de cette phrase complète est le nom « la juge », et cette juge est une femme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, l'accord du participe passé est attendu dans ce cas.

Verbe avoir et complément d'objet direct (**l'**) placé avant le verbe.

L'utilisation épicène de *juge* ne fait pas de doute puisqu'on trouve ***la** juge* auparavant.

Voir [cet article](https://www.redactionjuridique.chaire.ulaval.ca/la-feminisation-des-titres-dans-les-decisions-de-justice#:%7E:text=(R.)%2C%20l%27,et%20%C2%AB%20Madame%20le%20juge%20%C2%BB.&text=Aussi%2C%20l%27on%20observe%20que,le%20nom%20%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne%20%C2%AB%20juge%20%C2%BB.) sur le genre du mot juge.

Comment: C'est exact et il y a des phrases où ce n'est pas évident : une fille dira "Il m'a parlé, et puis il m'a conduite à la maison.", car c'est le "m'" est complément indirect dans le premier cas, et complément direct dans le second.

Comment: @Ben Un autre exemple: *il m'a menti, il m'a trahie*.